# Generate Authorization Token ZOHO CRM

Tags: zoho

While implementing ZOHO CRM with our website.
We found that there is a 3 steps authentication process to use the ZOHO CRM REST API.
We are entangled with the auth token generation process.

We have the following queries related to this

1. How to generate 'auth token' in Zoho projects via API mode. 
   I am able to generate Authtoken via 'Browser Mode' but stuck in generating auth token via API mode !! We are calling below URL mentioned in the documentation :
   `https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoCRM.users.ALL&client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&access_type={"offline"or"online"}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`
2. We want this to be automated to generate the "code" without hitting the "Accept" button and not have to do a self-client to generate the code every day?
   This is not a good solution to go.
   Do I need to generate the code every day manually? Isn't there any API to generate the auth code?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Visit  https://api-console.zoho.com/
and Make a self-client here

[image: Client Secret Tab]

1. using self client code you will get secret id & client id & auth code

[image: Generate Code Tab In Console]

2. Add scopes and Generate
3. Using this auth code you can use to create a refresh token(its valid until you cannot revoke it)
4. using Refresh token you can create an access token(valid 1 hr).
   used postman to quick creation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Browser mode. used self Client.

1. using self client code you will get secret id & client id & auth code
2. using this auth code you can use for to create a refresh token(its valid until you cannot revoke it)
3. using Refresh token you can create an access token(valid 1 hr).

used postman to quick creation.